# how to check if a checkbox has been selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML content:

```
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>

<div class="b_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="b_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="b_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="b_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="b_list"><input type="checkbox"></input><p>Testing A list </p></div>
```

and this jQuery:

```
if($(".a_list, .b_list").is(":checked"))
{

} else
{
    alert("Please make a selection");
}
```

Comment: Your code has NO checkboxes. IF it did your JS is asking if the object containing all checkboxes with classes of .a_list or .b_list is checked. It will return true if the first is checked but it's not going to test if they all are and tell you about it. Please explain more thoroughly.

Comment: What about the code that you have is not working? Further, your HTML has no checkboxes.

Comment: `<input></input>` is invalid. Before you hop into JS, review your HTML skills. Thumbs up and happy coding!

Comment: The question (the title) is still ambiguous

Comment: Your HTML may now have checkboxes, but it also technically doesn’t because none of your `<input>` tags are valid HTML. You also still fail to explain what is wrong with the current jQuery you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might mean "how to check if **at least one** checkbox is checked?"

```
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox" /><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox" /><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox" /><p>Testing A list </p></div>
<div class="a_list"><input type="checkbox" /><p>Testing A list </p></div>

if (!$(".a_list input:checked, .b_list input:checked").length){
     alert("Please make a selection");
}
```

inputs do not have `</input>`

Comment: thanks for understanding my question, I'll give it a try.

Comment: The `/` at the end of `input` is unnecessary. By definition, `<input>` does not need a self closing tag.

Comment: its working perfect, thanks a lot Popnoodles

Comment: @popnoodles - `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` HTML5

Comment: Clearly I know what I wrote it in. Spouting another doctype is constructive how?

Comment: @Derek, while we're not everybody still into HTML5 (like we all maybe should) you have to be more specific before giving firm statements. We had enough of w3schools ;)

Comment: Sorry for that, maybe I should say it in this way: The `/` at the end of `input` is unnecessary in HTML5 by defintion.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I still prefer XHTML self-closing tags - they make far more sense semantically, they are valid in HTML5 (for the tags they were always valid for) so I will continue to use them (purely for semantic reasons).

Comment: @Derek Not just HTML5, any version of HTML. Only XHTML requires self-closing of tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
if($(".a_list, .b_list").is(":checked"))
```

...checks whether any elements with class `a_list` or `b_list` are checked, which of course they won't be since they're all divs. To check whether any such elements have a child checkbox that is checked you can instead say:

```
if($(".a_list, .b_list").has(":checked").length > 0)
```

Where the [`.has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/) tests whether any element in the jQuery object it's called on has a descendant matching the supplied selector. (Noting that `.has()` returns another jQuery object, not a boolean.)

If for some reason you're determined to keep using `.is()` then you need to select the actual checkboxes first:

```
if($(".a_list, .b_list").find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked"))
// or
if($('.a_list input[type="checkbox"], .b_list input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked"))
```